# Advantages of fixing snapshot version in Maven

Tags: maven, version, snapshot

My project has snapshot dependencies for which no releases are available. If I fix the version, such as `<version>0.0.1-20140219.100706-347</version>` instead of `<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>`, do I now enjoy the benefits in speed of using releases or am I still subject to automatic updates slowing my build down just by using a dependency that resides in a snapshot repository? Are there any benefits of releases then other than having kind of a tag to a specific version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> do I now enjoy the benefits in speed of using releases or am I still subject to automatic updates slowing my build down

Yes; a timestamped `SNAPSHOT` version refers to a unique artifact, so Maven won't check again. You could also consider setting an update policy to reduce the frequency of checks ([How does the updatePolicy in maven really work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3805329/how-does-the-updatepolicy-in-maven-really-work)).

> Are there any benefits of releases then other than having kind of a tag to a specific version?

As a general practice, `SNAPSHOT` builds (even timestamped ones) aren't intended to stick around. Because you'll have one for every build it's normal to prune them (e.g. [How to limit number of deployed snapshots artifacts in Nexus?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12660850/how-to-limit-number-of-deployed-snapshots-artifacts-in-nexus)). At some point you'll want to pick a specific version that will be kept permanently, and which can be used for reproducible builds: that's what final release versions are for.