# Maven WAR packaging libraries with timestamp

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, nexus, sonatype

I have several libraries which I've manually deployed to my Nexus repository using:

```
mvn deploy:deploy-file -Durl=[url] -DrepositoryId=[repoId] -Dfile=[filePath] -DgroupId=[gId] -DartifactId=[aid] -Dversion=[v] -Dpackaging=jar
```

I did this because they are legacy jars and quite a large amount of them for which I've automated the process.

The problem I'm having is in packaging a WAR.  The dependencies come down just fine, but when the war is generated they have the version+timestamp appended to the end.  I have several other projects where this doesn't appear to be the scenario - i.e., after multiple packagings and deployments to a given server the lib directory [for the project] contains:

```
[jar].[<version>-timestamp1].jar
[jar].[<version>-timestamp2].jar
[jar].[<version>-timestamp3].jar
[jar].[<version>-SNAPSHOT].jar     <== this entry alone would be ideal
```

Also, I'm not using any specific plugins just invoking:

```
clean package
```

Is it possible to eliminate the timestamp when packaging the war?

Answer (score 2):

You may need to ask yourself why you need to eliminate the timestamp.

**If you just want to download the latest SNAPSHOT version**, Nexus provides [REST API](https://oss.sonatype.org/nexus-restlet1x-plugin/default/docs/path__artifact_maven_redirect.html) to download latest SNAPSHOT artifact just directly using your snapshot version as version parameter, such as `1.0-SNAPSHOT`. e.g.

```
http://<your-nexus>/service/local/artifact/maven/redirect?r=<your-repo>&g=<the-group>&a=<the-id>&v=1.0-SNAPSHOT
```

From the API doc, the version parameter can support `LATEST`, `RELEASE` and `SNAPSHOT` versions.

```
Version of the artifact (Required) Supports resolving of "LATEST", "RELEASE" and snapshot versions ("1.0-SNAPSHOT") too.
```

Furthermore, with timestamp each SNAPSHOT build has it's unique version, which gives you the chance to download a specified SNAPSHOT build such as `v=1.0-20140822.145007-2`.

**If you want to limit the number of snapshots**, you can take a look this one: [How to limit number of deployed snapshots artifacts in Nexus?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12660850/how-to-limit-number-of-deployed-snapshots-artifacts-in-nexus)

Comment: How would you manage the WEB-INF/lib over time?  Maybe I'm trying to solve a problem that supports both development and production environments, when they should differ...

Comment: You may open other question about managing WEB-INF/lib with more details.