# How to remove Maven-Artifactory from keeping timestamps for snapshot

Tags: maven, nexus

Is there any way to   remove the timestamp attached to maven Artifactory while deploying to repository.

Environment using:
            Maven 3.3.9,JDK 1.7,NEXUS 3

I am executing the maven deploy with “-uniqueVersion=false”  option and also  set the following one in pom.xml

```
<snapshotRepository>
            <id>snapshots</id>
<uniqueVersion>false</uniqueVersion>
            <name>Internal Snapshots</name>
            <url>******************/repository/maven-snapshots/</url>
        </snapshotRepository>
    </distributionManagement>
```

But still  timestamp  is attaching  to artifactory ,  What mistake  i am making can anyone guide me.

Uploaded: http://*******/repository/maven-snapshots/com/***/it/200655/***-rswebservices/2.3.135-SNAPSHOT/***-rswebservices-2.3.135-20170210.100546-7.war (48881 KB at 27631.6 KB/sec)
Uploading: http:/*******/repository/maven-snapshots/com/**/it/200655/**-rswebservices/2.3.135-SNAPSHOT/**-rswebservices-2.3.135-20170210.100546-7.pom
2/2 KB

Uploaded: http://*******/repository/maven-snapshots/com/****/it/200655/***-rswebservices/2.3.135-SNAPSHOT/***-rswebservices-2.3.135-20170210.100546-7.pom (2 KB at 53.0 KB/sec)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12660850/how-to-limit-number-of-deployed-snapshots-artifacts-in-nexus

Comment: What is the problem with this timestamp? Where does it bother you?

Comment: actually i want to control the number of artifactory ( war files )  in nexus .So if we dont  have  timestamp i hope it will override the Files in nexus

Comment: Mind filing an issue with us on this one? We'd like to check this out: https://issues.sonatype.org/browse/NEXUS

Comment: Hi , i have  put it in nexus jira as - NEXUS-12393